# Как отредактировать следующее предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

В команде руководителей должно практиковаться коллективное обсуждение стратегических и тактических проблем, выслушиваться все точки зрения, и только после этого приниматься решения.

Моя версия:

В команде руководителей должно практиковаться коллективное обсуждение стратегических и тактических проблем, должны выслушиваться все точки зрения и только после этого приниматься решения.

Т. е. запятую убрать, т. к. здесь предложения рассматриваются как однородные члены, и добавить слово "должны" для согласования... Это правильно?

Comment: Мне кажется, правильно. Запятая точно лишняя. А решений много? Может лучше так: "...и только после этого принимаются решения"?

Answer (score 1):

Это правильно.

А вот как сохранить запятую перед И, которая там явно не случайно поставлена, я не знаю. Хочется какой-то знак там поставить, чтобы отделить "потом" от "должны". Хоть тире ставь.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше предложение построено верно. ***В команде руководителей*** должно практиковаться коллективное обсуждение стратегических и тактических проблем, должны выслушиваться все точки зрения и только после этого приниматься решения.

Общий для трёх простых предложений втростепенный член ***в команде руководителей*** не позволяет ставить запятую перед И.

Comment: Екатерина, но тогда получается такой смысл: : должно практиковаться и  принятие решения. Вы рассматриваете предложение как сложное?

Answer (score 0):

Запятая в данном случае нужна, поскольку  "и только после этого приниматься решения" не входит в однородный ряд, который зависит от сказуемого "практиковаться", т. е. практиковаться должно только коллективное обсуждение стратегических и тактических проблем, выслушиваться все точки зрения. Предложение же "и только после этого приниматься решения" можно рассмотреть как присоединительное.

Comment: Но оно же входит в однородный ряд, зависящий от "должны".

Answer (score 0):

Значит, что у нас неправильно: *должно практиковаться обсуждение, выслушиваться, приниматься.*

Человеческая речь (максимально приближенная к оригиналу):

*В команде руководителей должно практиковаться коллективное обсуждение стратегических и тактических проблем, должны быть выслушаны все точки зрения и только после этого можно принимать решения.*

*Должно* и *должны* у меня сознательный повтор; хвостик предложения я просто облегчила, можно и

*...только после этого могут приниматься решения.*

А запятую - да, убрать. Если всё нравится, можете оставить свой вариант правки. Криминалу там нету.

Answer (score 0):

Использование слова "должны" правомочно только если вы, пишущий эту бумагу находитесь по рангу выше "команды руководителей" или являетесь их лидером.
Так же "команда руководителей" это чепуха какая то, аля колхоза без председателя, сплошные главнюки и кто главный главнюк ничерта не понятно, сам чёрт ногу сломает, в вашем коллективе.